# Connect to signalR hub from c# web api

Tags: c#, azure, signalr, azure-signalr

I've been tasked with trying to move our signalR hub to an azure cloud service with a service bus backplane.  No problems there.  The javascript client is able to get the hubs.js and connect without errors.  We also have a web api project that needs to send messages to the hub but I cannot get it to connect.  Everything I've tried doesn't work and the connection times out.  I must be missing something but, since this is my first time working with signalR and Azure, I don't know what it is. The web api is hosted on IIS.

Here is the code I am trying to use to connect:

```
    private async void InitializeHub()
    {
        string connectionString = "http://xxxx-xxxxx.cloudapp.net/signalr";
        var hubConnection = new HubConnection(connectionString, useDefaultUrl: false);
        //var hubConnection = new HubConnection(connectionString);
        HubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("clientPortalHub");
        await hubConnection.Start();
    }
```

Is there some configuration I am missing?  Anything need to be done in IIS?  I'm not getting any helpful error messages, just that the connection times out.  I can hit the url (the real one, not the one I pasted) in a browser and get "Unknown transport".

If it helps here is the startup from the hub:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Any connection or hub wire up and configuration should go here
        string connectionString = "<omitted>";
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseServiceBus(connectionString, "clientPortalHub");
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {

            map. UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                // EnableJSONP = true
            };

            hubConfiguration.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you try without useDefaultUrl: false ? You commented *new HubConnection(connectionString);* so I guess you checked this out too, just to be sure...

Comment: Have you tried the builtin method `app.MapSignalR("/signalr", new HubConfiguration());` for configuration?

Comment: Yes, I've tried without useDefaultUrl.  I will try the app.MapSinalR today and report back.